# ICA - Exercise Problem from book - Matlab Code

Tags: matlab, ica

Im trying to do a problem of ICA from a Image Processing book, but when I finish I got the Matrix C different from the one in the exercise.
This is the Exercise:
[image: Exercise]
[image: Exercise2]
This is my Matlab Code:

```
t=1:1000;
f=sin(t*pi/19);
g=sin(pi*t/5)+sin(pi*t/31);
h=mod(.3*t,1.5);
m1=.3*f+.4*g+.3*h;
m2=.5*f+.2*g+.3*h;
m3=.1*f+.1*g+.8*h;
mn=[m1;m2;m3];
m1p=m1-mean2(mn);
m2p=m2-mean2(mn);
m3p=m3-mean2(mn);
mnp=[m1p;m2p;m3p;];
C=(mnp*mnp')/3;
[V,D]=eig(C);
eigenvalues=diag(D);
eigenvector=V;
```

My result in the Matrix C is:

```
C =

   77.2656   60.7483   26.2664
   60.7483   64.0480   23.0485
   26.2664   23.0485   56.4664
```

This are the steps of the algorithm:
[image: Step0-1]
[image: Step2-3]
Then there is some info about applying to Signal Processing:
[image]

My problem is I don't get the same Matrix C from the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
C=(mnp*mnp')/3
```

you're dividing by 3 when you should really be dividing by the number of observations, which is 1000 in your case.

Comment: Oh you are right, it didnt look the same, but very close : C =

    0.2318    0.1822    0.0788
    0.1822    0.1921    0.0691
    0.0788    0.0691    0.1694 ! thank you very much